# Trouble speeding up algorithm

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I have made an algorithm in R to combine multiple sensor readings together under one timestamp.

Most sensor readings are taken every 500ms but some sensors only report changes. Therefor I had to make an algorithm that takes the last known value of a sensor at a given time.

Now the algorithm works, however it is so slow that when i would start using it for the actual 20+ sensors it would take ages to complete. My hypothesis is that it is slow because of my use of dataframes or the way I access and move my data.

I have tried making it faster by only walking trough every dataframe once and not iterating over them for every timestamp. I have also preallocated all space needed for the data.

Any suggestions would be very welcome. I am very new to the R language so I don't really know what datatypes are slow and which are fast.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(pracma)    

# take a list of dataframes as a parameter
generalise_data <- function(dataframes, timeinterval){
  if (typeof(dataframes) == "list"){
    # get the biggest and smallest datetime stamp from every dataframe
    # this will be used to calculate the size of the resulting frame ((largest time - smallest time)/1000 = dataframe rows)
    # this means one value every second

    largest_time <- 0
    smallest_time <- as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000 # everything will be smaller than the current time
    for (i in 1:length(dataframes)){
      dataframe_max <- max(dataframes[[i]]$TIMESTAMP)
      dataframe_min <- min(dataframes[[i]]$TIMESTAMP)

      if (dataframe_max > largest_time) largest_time <- dataframe_max
      if (dataframe_min < smallest_time) smallest_time <- dataframe_min
    }

    # result dataframe wil have ... rows
    result.size <- floor((largest_time - smallest_time)/timeinterval)
    sprintf("Result size: %i", result.size)

    # create a numeric array that contains the indexes of every dataframe, all set to 1
    dataframe_indexes <- numeric(length(dataframes))
    dataframe_indexes[dataframe_indexes == 0] <- 1

    # data vectors for the dataframe
    result.timestamps <- numeric(result.size)
    result <- list(result.timestamps)
    for (i in 2:(length(dataframes)+1)) result[[i]] <- numeric(result.size) # add an empty vector for every datapoint

    # use progressbar
    pb <- txtProgressBar(1, result.size, style = 3)

    # make a for loop to run through every data row of the resulting data frame (creating a row every run through)
    # every run through increase the index of dataframes until the resulting row exceeds the result rows timestamp, than go one index back
    #for (i in 1:200){
    for (i in 1:result.size){
      current_timestamp <- smallest_time + timeinterval*(i-1)
      result[[1]][i] <- current_timestamp

      for (i2 in 1:length(dataframes)){
        while (dataframes[[i2]]$TIMESTAMP[dataframe_indexes[i2]] < current_timestamp && dataframes[[i2]]$TIMESTAMP[dataframe_indexes[i2]] != max(dataframes[[i2]]$TIMESTAMP)){
            dataframe_indexes[i2] <- dataframe_indexes[i2]+1
        }

        if (dataframe_indexes[i2] > 1){
            dataframe_indexes[i2] <- dataframe_indexes[i2]-1 # take the one that's smaller
        }

        result[[i2+1]][i] <- dataframes[[i2]]$VALUE[dataframe_indexes[i2]]
      }

      setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    }

    close(pb)

    result.final <- data.frame(result)

    return(result.final)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}
```

Comment: If the code works, this probably belongs on [codereview.se]. Without delving into your code, it has an awful lot of loops. Finding ways to vectorize your code and/or use things like `sapply` to eliminate some of the loops might help. A book that I have found helpful: "Efficient R Programming" by Gillespie and Lovelace

Comment: I picked my loops very carefully the only one that takes more time than about 50ms is: `for (i in 1:result.size){` however there is a for loop in there which might be slowing it down a little bit... Thanks for the suggestion for posting it in Code Review

Comment: With `for .. for ... while` you have deeply nested loops, which might be the problem. There are profiling tools that can be used to pinpoint exactly where the problem is.

Comment: @Milan Please provide some data in order to be able to run your code.

Comment: @F.Privé when i get home from work i will try to make a script that can generate some data to run through the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it today by changing every dataframe to a matrix. The code ran in 9.5 seconds instead of 70 minutes.

Conclusion: dataframes are VERY bad for performance.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
library(pracma)
library(compiler)    

# take a list of dataframes as a parameter
generalise_data <- function(dataframes, timeinterval){
  time.start <- Sys.time()
  if (typeof(dataframes) == "list"){
    # store the sizes of all the dataframes
    resources.largest_size <- 0
    resources.sizes <- numeric(length(dataframes))

    for (i in 1:length(dataframes)){
      resources.sizes[i] <- length(dataframes[[i]]$VALUE)
      if (resources.sizes[i] > resources.largest_size) resources.largest_size <- resources.sizes[i]
    }

    # generate a matrix that can hold all needed dataframe values
    resources <- matrix(nrow = resources.largest_size, ncol = length(dataframes)*2)
    for (i in 1:length(dataframes)){
      j <- i*2
      resources[1:resources.sizes[i],j-1] <- dataframes[[i]]$TIMESTAMP
      resources[1:resources.sizes[i],j] <- dataframes[[i]]$VALUE
    }

    # get the biggest and smallest datetime stamp from every dataframe
    # this will be used to calculate the size of the resulting frame ((largest time - smallest time)/1000 = dataframe rows)
    # this means one value every second
    largest_time <- 0
    smallest_time <- as.numeric(Sys.time())*1000 # everything will be smaller than the current time
    for (i in 1:length(dataframes)){
      dataframe_max <- max(dataframes[[i]]$TIMESTAMP)
      dataframe_min <- min(dataframes[[i]]$TIMESTAMP)

      if (dataframe_max > largest_time) largest_time <- dataframe_max
      if (dataframe_min < smallest_time) smallest_time <- dataframe_min
    }

    # result dataframe wil have ... rows
    result.size <- floor((largest_time - smallest_time)/timeinterval)
    sprintf("Result size: %i", result.size)

    # create a numeric array that contains the indexes of every dataframe, all set to 1
    dataframe_indexes <- numeric(length(dataframes))
    dataframe_indexes[dataframe_indexes == 0] <- 1

    # data matrix for the result
    result <- matrix(data = 0, nrow = result.size, ncol = length(dataframes)+1)

    # use progressbar
    pb <- txtProgressBar(1, result.size, style = 3)

    # make a for loop to run through every data row of the resulting data frame (creating a row every run through)
    # every run through increase the index of dataframes until the resulting row exceeds the result rows timestamp, than go one index back
    #for (i in 1:200){
    for (i in 1:result.size){
      current_timestamp <- smallest_time + timeinterval*(i-1)
      result[i,1] <- current_timestamp

      for (i2 in 1:length(dataframes)){
        j <- i2*2
        while (resources[dataframe_indexes[i2],j-1] < current_timestamp && resources[dataframe_indexes[i2],j-1] != resources.sizes[i2]){
          dataframe_indexes[i2] <- dataframe_indexes[i2]+1
        }

        # at the moment the last value of the array is never selected, needs to be fixed
        if (dataframe_indexes[i2] > 1){
          dataframe_indexes[i2] <- dataframe_indexes[i2]-1 # take the one that's smaller
        }

        result[i,i2+1] <- resources[dataframe_indexes[i2], j] #dataframes[[i2]]$VALUE[dataframe_indexes[i2]]
      }

      setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    }

    close(pb)

    result.final <- data.frame(result)

    time.end <- Sys.time()
    print(time.end-time.start)

    return(result.final)
  } else {
    return(NA)
  }
}
```